# iOS7 searchDisplayController hides tableview indexes

Tags: ios, ios7, tableview

Have a tableview with indexes. They are visible on initial load.

I also have a searchDisplayController

When I use the searchDisplayController and then cancel out of it, suddenly the indexes on the original tableview are hidden.

I never had this problem with iOS 6.

Here is my code that worked with iOS 6:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView2 {

 if (self.searchDisplayController.active)
    return nil;

else
    return self.indices;
}
```

I've tried this with no luck:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    [self.tableViewOriginal reloadSectionIndexTitles];
}

- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    [self.tableViewOriginal reloadSectionIndexTitles];
}
```

UPDATE:

To add the tableView I use a storyboard and connect it with an IBOutlet. The searchBar and searchDisplayController are added programmatically in viewDidLoad:

```
  self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 290, 44)]; 
  self.searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
```

I then add the searchbar to a table cell if cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 [cell addSubview:self.searchBar];
```

Comment: I have a table view that shows the table view indexes. I also use a search display controller that doesn't show the indexes. When the search is canceled, the main table's indexes reappear just fine. This is under iOS 6 and 7. So it normally works just fine. So there must be something you are doing. Update your question with more details about how you setup the search display controller and search bar.

Comment: Where's the rest of the code to finish setting up the search display controller? Do you setup its delegates?

Comment: @maddy yeah I omitted that because I didn't think it mattered. I set the delegates to self. I also set the searchResultsDataSource to self. Self being the view controller its hosted in

Comment: That all seems fine. The only other suggestion I have is to change how you show the search bar. Instead of adding it to a table cell, make the search bar the table view's `headerView`.

Comment: Wow placing the SearchBar in the tableHeaderView worked! Make this an answer so I can accept it. 2,395 answers and 8 questions? VOTE @rmaddy FOR MODERATOR!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible issue with your setup is that you are putting the search bar in a table view cell.

A more standard (and much simpler) approach is to make the search bar the table view's `headerView`.

```
self.tableView.headerView = self.searchBar;
```

Just do this once just after setting up the search display controller.